# Registering with Ubuntu One

Tags: software-recommendation, single-sign-on

I have installed Ubuntu and trying to register for update and have 2 hours to sign to Ubuntu One.

The signup page is not readable - I can't see where to register and use the email on my laptop which has Ubuntu on it.

Comment: There is no need to register for updated, and no email is required for anything.

Comment: @mikewhatever What about to sign into Ubuntu One - that needs an email, no?

Comment: it is not letting me go beyond unless I register to enable the feature

Comment: @Zahid Can you take a photo to show us it?

Comment: I will upload but now I got tired of re-tries and powered it off

Comment: @Zahid Are you sure there is not an orange x in the top left corner to close it? When you send a photo we will be able to help more. Upload to http://imgur.com.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One storage was discontinued in April 2014. [This was for various reasons](https://login.ubuntu.com/one-redirect).

However, Ubuntu One still exists as a way to sign into [Launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net), [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/) and here, [Ask Ubuntu](http://ask.ubuntu.com). It also enables recommendations on the Software Centre.

To sign in, open the Software Centre by searching the dash for it. Then click the "Turn on Recommendations" button and it will open the sign up window.

Here you can sign up / in to Ubuntu One. However it is not a requirement, and if you don't want to, simply click the orange `x` in the top left of the window.

[image]

Comment: one are the other way, I got my login worked,  after so many step, it created my account and I am good now. thanks for all your help

Comment: @Zahid Please click the grey tick button below the down arrow to mark as solved!